# Add flutter web and desktop to existing flutter (android/ios) project in android studio

Tags: flutter

I know it maybe still early but I want to try and use full flutter existing cross-platform support in one project. **Stability is not my main concern.**

I have started a flutter project in android studio. Naturally I have (android/Ios) going smoothly. But I would love to add Web and desktop to the same project.

Please help me with and direction, or if there is solution any one has created however much experimental.

Comment: That's currently not possible. Flutter_web is based on a fork of Flutter, you can't mixt it with existing flutter projects.

Comment: does that mean one can get it to work is you start from scratch, with the  forked version?

Comment: For desktop, you can [manually add desktop support to your project using the flutter-desktop-embedding example](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/Quick-Start.md).

Comment: No, that means for now you cannot share code between web and other platforms.

Comment: @RémiRousselet what about this? Flutter official doc says
"To add web support to an existing project, run the following command in a terminal."
flutter create .

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#add-web-support-to-an-existing-app

Answer (score 1):

There is a migration guide for web [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/docs/migration_guide.md). I got it up and running on a very basic existing app.

Best way is to do it in a separate branch since it requires changing packages and I even deleted .packages and pubspec.lock files first. Then I ran `pub get` (not `flutter packages get`) to download the required packages and run some precompilers.