# VSCode and AndroidStudio Project setup to run flutter for device, web (and desktop?)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have read a [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208049/add-flutter-web-and-desktop-to-existing-flutter-android-ios-project-in-android) which states **Flutter Web** is a fork of Flutter and so one Android Studio (or VScode) project can't be built to handle both. 
I'm not an expert on either (obviously) but I don't understand why the fact the libraries are forked implicitly precludes one from using the same source code for the different destinations.

Has anyone done so? And, if so, is there a skeletal project anyone would care to share?